# Predicates using generics in java 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, predicate

I am new to Java Generics and Streams

Code 1

```
Predicate<DataObject> p1 = e -> doEvaluate(e.getAttribute1());
```

Code 2

```
Predicate<Entry<Integer, List>> p2 =  e -> doEvaluate(e.getKey());
```

Here DataObject is a pure Java Class and getAttribute1() is the getter method in the class DataObject.
and  Entry implies to the EntrySet of a hashmap.

Now I want to write a single line of code common to Code 1 and Code 2. How can I do it?

Comment: You can only make code "generic" if it is the code does the same thing for all versions (just acting on different classes). That's not the case here. One version calls `getKey`, one does not.

Comment: How does `doEvaluate` method look like?

Comment: ` private static Boolean doEvaluate(Object i) {
  
  return true;
 }
 
 `

Comment: Then what’s the point of these two predicates? Just write `x->true`…

Comment: Can you tell us what you are actually trying to do?